# Parsing Javascript code using Flex parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

My motive is to mangle variable and function names and also encrypt strings in a javascript file.

For this I only need to separate strings, comments, and variable/function names.

I've tried [UglifyJs2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) but I need more control on myself so I tried to write a lexer myself using Flex.

I'm able to take care of comments and quoted strings.

However I'm stuck in regular expression format for example **`/"/`** -- a regular expression containing quotes causing correct parsing to fail.

Looks like to correctly identify a regular expression i'd need Bison parser using grammar rules otherwise comments, strings and regular expression get mixed up.
I don't want to get that far and use Bison.

One way is to move all regular expression code to another file in functions.

**Is there any other alternative so that I can handle this in Flex itself?**

Comment: In flex it should be enough to add a rule to keep RE unchanged. Exampel  `[/].*[/]  {ECHO;}`  (naif version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run JavaScript, you can use [Esprima](http://esprima.org/), a JavaScript parser coded in JavaScript. It can even run in your browser or any runtime like NodeJS.

It can output just tokens or abstract syntax trees. I believe that this should enough for you.

Comment: Yes this is what I want!

Comment: But is it possible to build the code back using the output of Esprima? I'll have chance to replace specific tokens then.

Comment: @user5858 Well, this is another story! It seems like Esprima modified AST can be turned into JS again using this other project: https://github.com/estools/escodegen. In fact, this Esprima demo does it using that project... http://esprima.org/demo/rewrite.html